# Need help to proove that $f(x) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{Vol(B_\epsilon(x))}\int_{B_\epsilon(x)}f(y)dy$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations

> Let $f\in C(\mathbb R^N)$ which denotes that $f$ is continuous over $\mathbb R^N$. Prove that $$f(x) = \lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\frac{1}{\text{Vol}(B_\epsilon(x))}\int_{B_\epsilon(x)}f(y)dy.$$

I tried to evaluate $\left|\frac{1}{\text{Vol}(B_\epsilon(x))}\int_{B_\epsilon(x)}f(y)dy-f(x)\right|$, but I am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: Since $f$ is continuous, it is uniformly continuous on compact subsets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Assuming $f$ is continuous at $x_0$, then there exists $\delta' > 0$ such that $|f(x)-f(x_0)| < \epsilon/2$ whenever $|x-x_0| < \delta'$. Then, for $0 < \delta < \delta'$,
$$
   \left|\frac{1}{\int_{|x-x_0|\le \delta}dx}\int_{|x-x_0| \le \delta}f(x)dx-f(x_0)\right| \\
  = \left|\frac{1}{\int_{|x-x_0|\le\delta}dx}\int_{|x-x_0|\le \delta}(f(x)-f(x_0))dx\right| \\
  \le \frac{1}{\int_{|x-x_0|\le\delta}dx}\int_{|x-x_0|}|f(x)-f(x_0)|dx \\
  \le \frac{1}{\int_{|x-x_0|\le\delta}dx}\frac{\epsilon}{2}\int_{|x-x_0|\le\delta}dx < \epsilon.
$$

Comment: how exactly the fact that $\left|\frac{1}{\int_{|x-x_0|\le \delta}dx}\int_{|x-x_0| \le \delta}f(x)dx-f(x_0)\right| < \varepsilon$ for every $\delta$ such that $0 < \delta < \delta'$ ensure that $f(x) = \lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0}\frac{1}{Vol(B_\epsilon(x))}\int_{B_\epsilon(x)}f(y)dy$?

Comment: @George : What I proved is this: Given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $\delta' > 0$ such that $|\cdots| \lt \epsilon$ whenever $0 < \delta < \delta'$. And, here, $\delta^n$ is a constant times the volume of the ball of radius $\delta$ centered at $x_0$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**
For each $\varepsilon>0$ you can define $x_{\max,\varepsilon}\in B_\varepsilon(x)$ and $x_{\min,\varepsilon}\in B_\varepsilon(x)$ such that 
$$
f(x_{\min,\varepsilon})\leq f(y)\leq f(x_{\max,\varepsilon})\text{ for all }y\in B_\varepsilon(x).
$$
Use this to estimate the integral and consider what happens to $x_{\min,\varepsilon}$ and $x_{\max,\varepsilon}$ if $\varepsilon\to 0$.